# Extensible external metadata standards?

Tags: language-agnostic, cross-platform, metadata, standards, xmp

Are there any standard or popular methods of storing external metadata for many generic purposes? I've heard of XMP but how popular is it besides embedded in JPEG images? I'm looking for a format I can use for anything including text files and compressed archives, especially something with implementations in many languages.

Or does everybody roll their own?

*UPDATE*

I'd prefer a solution not tied to any specific language or platform.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever watched a [MKV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) movie?

[Extensible Binary Meta Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Binary_Meta_Language)

There are other implementations and [related projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML)

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of MKV before. The binary XML's seem pretty interesting and I'm going to read up on them but they just seem like metaformats just like XML rather than any kind of standard format for metadata. So such metadata wouldn't be any more interchangeable without the standard.